# Separating title from thumbnail on wordpress

Tags: php, css, wordpress, themes, sidebar

I'm doing a wordpress theme and I'm trying to create some margins between a thumbnail and a post title on the recent posts on my sidebar. I tried everything but it just won't work. Any tips?

```
<?php $recent_posts = wp_get_recent_posts();
foreach( $recent_posts as $recent ){
if($recent['post_status']=="publish"){
if ( has_post_thumbnail($recent["ID"])) {
    echo '<li style=" list-style: none; ">
    <a class="post-title" href="' . get_permalink($recent["ID"]) . '" title="Look '.esc_attr($recent["post_title"]).'" >' .   get_the_post_thumbnail($recent["ID"], 'thumbnail').$recent["post_title"].'</a></li> ';
}else{
    echo '<li style=" list-style: none; ">
    <a class="post-title" href="' . get_permalink($recent["ID"]) . '" title="Look '.esc_attr($recent["post_title"]).'" >' .   $recent["post_title"].'</a></li> ';
}
 }
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried insert a break line between them?

```
get_the_post_thumbnail($recent["ID"], 'thumbnail') . '<br />' . $recent["post_title"].'
```

OR

add this to the CSS file:

```
img.attachment-thumbnail { margin:10px; }
```

Comment: Hey, thanks for helping me. And yes, the css worked! Now, the problem is that the title is on the bottom and not on the top. It looks like this: i.imgur.com/WggSQWQ.png And I want it to look like this: i.imgur.com/oAaSLpt.png I can't position the text on the right spot and I think it's due to the code that I posted previously.

Comment: I think, the easiest way is to add one or more break line after title, so:

`$recent["post_title"].'<br />'.` OR `$recent["post_title"].'<br /><br /><br />'.`

Comment: Unfortunately, it didn't work. tbh, nothing changed :/ With the 3 <br/>, the only thing that changes is the space between the "rows"